# How to print PDF with number page same number canvas using jsPDF?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf, canvas

I use jsPDF, which printed everything from canvas to PDF, but it can only frist canvas, I want to print PDF with number of page same number canvas. Sample : I have a div with 4 canvas, when export to PDF, get 4 pages landscape.

```js
$('#export').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var canvas = document.getElementById("pdf");
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var pdf = new jsPDF("l", "pt", "a4");
  pdf.addImage(canvas.toDataURL("image/png", 2), 'JPEG', 0, 0, width, height);
  pdf.save("file.pdf");
});
```

```html
<div id="pdf">
<canvas id="canvas_1" ></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas_2" ></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas_3" ></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas_4" ></canvas>
</div>
<button id="export">Print</button>
```

I get error at line `canvas.getContext is not a function`.

Comment: `canvas.getContext is not a function.` You are getting the error because `var canvas = document.getElementById("pdf");` here canvas is container div element not a canvas element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('#export').click(function (e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 var pdf = new jsPDF("l", "pt", "a4");
 var canvasEl = document.querySelectorAll("canvas");
 canvasEl.forEach(function(canvas,index){
  canvas.getContext('2d').fillRect(50,50,50*(index+1),50*(index+1));
  pdf.addImage(canvas.toDataURL("image/png", 2), 'JPEG', 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  if(index == canvasEl.length-1 ){
   pdf.save("file.pdf");
  }
  else {
   pdf.addPage();
  }
 })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.5/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pdf">
<canvas id="canvas_1" ></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas_2" ></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas_3" ></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas_4" ></canvas>
</div>
<button id="export">Print</button>
```

Get all the canvas element and loop through that node list, add page using `addPage()` method, and on last iteration save the pdf.